# Pandas Merge using a linspace column results in unexpected NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to do a left join in Pandas

```
dfla = pd.DataFrame({'score': [-2.0,-1.9,-1.8,-1.7,-1.6,-1.5,-1.4,-1.3,-1.2,-1.1,-1.0,
                              -0.9,-0.8,-0.7,-0.6,-0.5,-0.4,-0.3,-0.2,-0.1,0.0,
                              0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,
                              1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2.0],
                    'ext_rank':[1133,4333,4555,2222,4455,1431,4343,
                               1133,4333,4555,2222,4455,1431,4343,
                               1133,4333,4555,2222,4455,1431,4343,
                               1133,4333,4555,2222,4455,1431,4343,
                               1133,4333,4555,2222,4455,1431,4343,
                               1133,4333,4555,2222,4455,1311]
                             })
dfla
df_score = pd.Series(np.linspace(-2, 2, 41), name='score').to_frame()
result = pd.merge(df_score, 
                  dfla, on="score", how='left')
result
```

Why would this result in all of these NaNs?
[image]

Comment: Check the result of `df_score['score'].eq(dfla['score'])`?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to floating point approximation.

You can `round` the values:

```
df_score = pd.Series(np.linspace(-2, 2, 41), name='score').round(1).to_frame()
```

`merge` output:

```
    score  ext_rank
0    -2.0      1133
1    -1.9      4333
2    -1.8      4555
3    -1.7      2222
4    -1.6      4455
5    -1.5      1431
6    -1.4      4343
7    -1.3      1133
8    -1.2      4333
9    -1.1      4555
10   -1.0      2222
11   -0.9      4455
12   -0.8      1431
13   -0.7      4343
14   -0.6      1133
15   -0.5      4333
16   -0.4      4555
17   -0.3      2222
18   -0.2      4455
19   -0.1      1431
20    0.0      4343
...
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried df_score.score.round(1) but that apparently doesn't work as well!

Comment: I works with the provided example. Maybe also round dfla's score? If really this fails and you need a left merge you should use `merge_asof` with `direction='nearest'`